# Heroku doesn't update graphql schema once redeployed

Tags: mongodb, heroku, deployment, express-graphql

I am new to Heroku, MongoDb, Graphql and the development.
I created an app, deployed it to Heroku, everything was working just fine until I changed my schema (added 3 new fields). I used git push heroku main, heroku restart, and nothing seem to happen. When I go to localhost everything is updated and works just fine, meaning I can create users using new schema.
Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure you committed your changes before pushing? Did the correct commits get pushed? Did you push to the `main` or `master` branch, or another one?

Comment: I double checked and you are right. Embarrassed and grateful! Thank you, Chris